# How to recover value from regular expression

Tags: filenames

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right way or if it is possible at all. I want to change the name of some files using their own name.

Let's assume I have file1, file2, and file3. I want to do something like:

```
mv file* file{recover_number}_xyz
```

To get: file1_xyz, file2_xyz and file3_xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools which can apply a regex search-and-replace to the entire filename, e.g. `perl-rename` (also commonly called `prename`). In such tools, you would match multiple digits with `\d+` or `[0-9]+` inside a "capture group" (parentheses), and reference it later with `$1` or `\1` depending on program.

For example:

```
prename -v 's/file(\d+)$/file$1_xyz/' file[123]

prename -v 's/(file\d+)$/$1_xyz/' file[123]
```

*(The `-v` option makes prename print out the changes. You can use `-n` to print changes without actually renaming anything.)*

You can also achieve this using just `mv` and `sed`:

```
for old in file[123]; do
    new=$(sed -r 's/file([0-9]+)$/file\1_xyz/' <<< "$old")
    mv -v "$old" "$new"
done
```

---

But if you look closely, **you don't actually need the number.** All you're doing is appending some static text anyway, like this:

```
prename 's/$/_xyz/' file[123]

for f in file[123]; do
    mv "$f" "${f}_xyz"
done
```